# Select MAX in mixed int/string in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database:

```
+-------------+
| rd          |
+-------------+
| 65000807:11 |
| 65000807:9  |
| 65000809:10 |
+-------------+
```

I would like to select the biggest value, which is `65000807:11` (the biggest number after the `:`). With the following query, I can get `11`, but I need to get the whole string. How could I do that?

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(rd,10,length(rd)-9) AS UNSIGNED)) AS 'rd' from myTable;
```

Comment: Put the CAST in the ORDER BY instead, LIMIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your substring in an order by clause and get 1 result :

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  `rd` VARCHAR(11)
);

INSERT INTO myTable
  (`rd`)
VALUES
  ('65000807:11'),
  ('65000807:9'),
  ('65000809:10');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT rd
FROM myTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(rd,10,length(rd)-9) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Output :

```
| rd          |
| ----------- |
| 65000807:11 |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ag67AkFzfwPZEva8bTN7Q3/0)

---

However, I would advice you to re-think the design of the table, you are storing 2 informations in the same column, which goes against the purpose of using a RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

If the first number can be variable length, you better use `locate`:

```
select cast(substring(rd, locate(':', rd)+1) as signed)
from thetable
order by 1 desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `substring_index()` and `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by substring_index(rd, ':', -1) + 0 desc
limit 1;
```